# Azure Elastic Job running a stored procedure says it completes but is faster than in SSMS

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

I've set up an Azure Elastic Job to run a Stats Update on several Azure SQL Shards.

When I run this SP on the shards from SSMS some are quick and some take over an hour.

When I run the Elastic Job it finishes all of them in a few minutes.

My concern is that the Elastic Job, while it says it's running the stats, update SP it's not actually doing it because it's so quick to finish.

How can I figure out what is going on here?

Comment: I guess no one is using Azure Elastic Jobs and SQL SP's since there has been zero comments :(